# Ruby on Rails: Is there a better approach to achieve this "preview" feature I developed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, get

I have this "preview" feature in my app. The button appear in the edit page, when clicked it will take user to a new page that show how the form will look like when printed/downloaded. This "preview" feature will show data in the form without saving to database. For example if I change "note: field value from "note" to "edited note", in the preview page it will show "edited note" but in database the value is still "note".

I already achieved this, I'm sending form data to the preview method and then assign the data to already existing record via `assign_attributes()`. The problem is, that form data containing soo many nested attributes and because of this the link is sooo long, it is GET method btw. I believe this is not a good thing, isn't it? so is there any other way to achieve this without showing params in the url? or a way to make the params in the link sorter?

Here's the code, I'm sorry for not using my actual code but the logic is same
edit url: `/modul/:id/edit`
preview url: `/modul/:id/preview?long_parameter`

view

```
<%= button_tag 'Preview', type: "button", class: "btn btn-outline-success mr-1", id: "preview" %>


$("#preview").click(function(){
  var params = $("#record_form").serialize()
  window.location = "preview?" + params
})
```

controller

```
def preview
  # I'm using this logic 'cause @existing_record.assign_attributes(record_params) didn't update the children and grandchildren attributes
  @existing_record.children.each do |child|
    child_params = record_params[:children_attributes].values.select{|v| v[:id].to_i == child.id}.first
    child.assign_attributes(child_params.except(:grandchildren_attributes))
    child.grandchildren.each do |granchild|
      grandchild_params = child_params[:grandchildren_attributes].values.select{|v| v[:id].to_i == grandchild.id}.first
      grandchild.assign_attributes(grandchild_params)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: in the past, I used to do something similar, but it can get unwieldy. I ended up rewriting the lot and creating "shadow tables" to store the information in, with the "do it" button copying the desired records from the "shadow" to the "live" tables ... it also potentially survives if the browser crashes

Comment: Using versioning on pages that are "published" and "unpublished" could make this easier, but for your specific set up I'm not sure why the size of the URL matters at all and should be fine.  If you are looking for a totally better way to do it, my opinion would be to set up versioning for your pages so you have the active, published version and then could have a version that is only in preview

Comment: how about a transaction: save -> render preview -> rollback

Comment: Well, I try to serialize my form data from 2 different record, when I put the serialized data to ms word, the first one took one whole A4 page, and the second took 16 page, so of course I would be concerned to put this to my URL @RockwellRice

Comment: If I move the logic in preview method to a new POST method, put ```@existing_record``` into session and redirect to preview. In preview I'm gonna take the record in session and put it in ```@existing_record``` again. That way my URL will be clean, right? How's your opinion about this? is it okay to use session to keep object data like that?

If that way's no good I think I'm gonna go with something like "shadow tables" @Jad suggested.

Also, thanks for the response!

Comment: sessions work very well, unless you have a person who uses multiple tabs/windows. POST will get you past the limit on URL size, compared to GET, and you should be able to preview based on an object created with the POST data, without a save.

Answer (score 1):

For that purpose I would use the browser LocalStorage and serialize the deeply nested data structure so everything is kept on the frontend until the user is ready to save to the database.

Comment: I see, cmiiw, but in that case, I need to load all the data needed to the frontend right? If so I think it's not suitable for my case as I need to take quite a lot of data from my master table to do some logic. And thanks for the response!